# The simplest way to implement my Ruby code to an online tool

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have written Ruby code to convert a number to words.
Am running it on my ruby console locally.

So now, am considering a very simple webpage with an input text field for users to enter the number and an output field to display the result.

I could have written the code in Javascript, but I preferred to hide the code from users, and at the same time I wanted to get my hands dirty trying to learn Ruby.

So now, what are my options, should I use Sinatra (heard it is the most basic framework) or can it be done without any framework?

Comment: even if someone says that you "should" do something, you would be better off to decide for yourself anyway. Sinatra is good because you can spend less time programming your web site. Doing it from scratch is good too because then you will have no dependencies and can implement it to be more efficient. You question basically is not a good fit for this site because it cannot be answered adequately.

Comment: another option is `EventMachine`: http://rubyeventmachine.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ruby frameworks to pick from. Sinatra, but also Rails, Padrino, and a few lightweight ones line Camping.

If you really want to get your hands dirty, you could also build a Rack app without using any of them:

http://m.onkey.org/ruby-on-rack-1-hello-rack

Comment: Actually am learning Rails for a bigger project idea I have, and I really prefer to do this with Rails, so I don't learn many frameworks, But wouldn't be inefficient to use rails for such a small tool!

Comment: Yeah. But then again, isn't Rails inefficient for much about everything? :-) In all seriousness, if you're looking for efficiency of code rather than efficiency of coders, you shouldn't be looking into building ruby web apps at all.